# Sticky media controls, like in the Spotify app

Tags: android

I'm looking to create a view, with controls to control a mediaplayer, that sticks to the bottom of the screen in my app, like in the Spotify app. I have not found anything on Google that points me in the right direction. Got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the Spotify app some more i've com to the conclution that the player is not an overlay as that, but a fragment that get's hidden or shown depending on if it's playing or not. That is how i have implemented it now.

Comment: That is how i implemented it as well.